# What is $f'(x)$ if $f(x)$ is a cumulative function

Tags: integration, derivatives, mathematical-modeling

Let me preface by saying that I am completely ignorant of the math covered in Calculus 2, which for me includes integration. All I know is that the integral is the area under a curve, which I understand as the sum total of all data points up to a given value of $x$, and that the derivative of an integral is just the original function.

I'm working on a problem where I'm given $f '(t)$, and I know that $f(t)$ is the number of errors made by a shift worker from $t = 0$ to $t$. To me, $f(t)$ sounds like an integral, since it describes the total errors made by the worker till $t$. My question then is, would $f'(t)$ be some function (let's say $g$), whose integral is $f(t)$?

The difference in my analysis is that $g(t)$ would be the number of errors made at the instant $t$, while a typical derivative is be the rate that errors are occurring at $t$.

Comment: You say you are given the function f'(t) if it is given it must mean something measurable, since you can not make errors in an exakt moment t, you alway would need a time interval $\Delta t$ to make errors. Can you give an example how f'(t) is given and what exactly it means?

Comment: I'm not allowed to give out information directly, but f(t) is the total number of errors made from t = 0 to t, and f'(t) is the "instantaneous rate of change" of errors made.

Comment: Typically this $f(t)$ would change discretely (by jumps at each instant when an error is made), and so its derivative is not an ordinary function like you are used to. There is a concept for describing the derivative of a function with jumps, but I think at your level explaining this would be more confusing than illuminating.

Comment: By discretely do you mean something like a step function? Would it be easier to describe the antiderivative for this particular problem, since I'm given the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'll assume that this is a continous probability case and not discrete one, because if it's a discrete probability the integral interpretation doesn't apply. I'll also define cumulative function as $\mathbf F(t)$ and it's derivative as $\mathbf F'(t) = f(t)$.

Please note that nothing below applies if you are given an event probability table or a cumulative function that looks like this:
$$\mathbf F(t) = \begin{cases}
0.2, \ 0\leq t \leq 2\\ 
0.6, \ 2\leq t \leq 4\\ 
1, \ 4\leq t
\end{cases}
$$
This is a discrete case and no integral can be applied to it.

By definition, a cumulative function $\mathbf F(t)$ returns **a probability** that something is less than or equal to $t$. In your case I suppose it would return **a probability** that there was no more than $t$ errors made by a worker. Taking a derivative of that function, in some sense, would give you a rate of change, but more importantly the derivative of cumulative function $\mathbf F(t)$ is probability density function $f(t)$. That is, by taking a derivative you still get a function.

You can find online images of cumulative and probability density functions plotted together. They tell slightly different story. While $\mathbf F(t)$ tells the probability of something happening no more than $t$, the probability density allows you to take a look at the probability that some value of $t$ lies in some region $[a,b]$. That probability is in fact defined as the integral $\int_a^b f(t) \ dt$.

You can ask "What is the probability that a worker makes at least 3 and no more than 5 mistakes?". You can calculate the integral $\int_3^5 f(t) \ dt$ to find out.

Alternatively, you can make use of that definition and only use the cumulative $\mathbf F(t)$. Since $\mathbf F(t)$ tells the probability that your worker performas no more than $t$ mistakes, asking $\mathbf F(5) - \mathbf F(3)$ would produce the same result as integrating. To make it more obvious $\mathbf F(5) - \mathbf F(3) = \int_0^5 f(t) \ dt \ - \int_0^3 f(t) \ dt = \int_3^5 f(t) \ dt$, thanks to the properties of an integral.

Using the language of math, here you're considering the probability that your worker performs anywhere from 0 to 5 mistakes (which of course includes making  anywhere from 0 to 3 mistakes) and you subtract the probability that he makes 0 to 3 mistakes, leaving only the probability to make 3, 4 or 5 mistakes.

Comment: I am almost certain that f(t) is continuous (not discrete) in this example, but I don't believe that it  gives the probability that an error will occur. f'(x) is based on a  data model following an individual's performance over the course of their shift. The analysis of the data is used to predict future trends, but the data itself is discrete. I'm sure some aspects of this problem were simplified to keep to the scope of the course.

Comment: I think you should provide a bit more details on things that you are given in this problem and things that you want to find. Depending on specifics, it may go either way - discrete or continous. It's difficult to suggest something other than exact definitions of what a cumulative F(t) and probability density f(t) are. I'm also not sure - are you actually given any function or is it just pure data? For example a probability distribution function could look something like this f(t) = g * e^(-g*t), where g is some constant and t is a variable.

Comment: Again, I'm mostly curious wether f(t) function describes an integral, and what the implications of that would be in my analysis of f'(t) (as opposed to the derivative of a typical function).

Comment: Yes, as I pointed out f'(t) and f(t) are related via said integral. The derivative actually tells you what are the most probable values of t (number of errors), where as the cumulative f(t) tells you the probability that there is no more than t errors made. Plot both of them on the interval of t = [0,10] to make it more visual, use wolframalpha if you aren't sure how to integrate that function. Also I'll say that a function doesn't "describe" an integral, an integral is just a number like 3 or 7. Functions, though, can be related via integral if h(x) = g'(x), then integral(h(x)) = g(x) + C.

Comment: The weird thing is that both of these functions f'(t) and f(t) should be divided by 10 to make sense of the probability interpretation, but I guess these are up to semantics of the assignment.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the best answer I can get with what I'm working with, so I'll run with it. If the function looks unusual, it's because I'm going a little outside the scope of the course in my analysis, (mostly just out of curiosity).

Answer (score 0):

If you can plot f'(t) you just measure the area under the curve  from 0 to t to obtain f(t). So I still strongly doubt that one can measure the  "instantaneous rate of change"